# Creating nested records on create with Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-activerecord

I have a projects model that I am using to auto generate departments within a specific project on create.  This is included in the `projects` model with:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :departments_attributes, :positions_attributes, :id
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :departments
    has_many :positions
    validates :title, presence: true

    before_create :set_departments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions

    private
       def set_departments
            self.departments.build department: "Test Dept", production_id: self.id

       end

end
```

Each department has many positions.  I am trying to create positions as well for the departments.  How could I associate a new position with a department in this model?

Comment: So, project has_many positions, and department has_many positions?

Comment: I put that line in there as an attempt to do this. I guess the correct way would be project `has_many: departments` and departments `has_many: positions`.

Comment: Yep, that's sounds good. And then project has_many positions, through: departments, fun fun fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :departments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments

   before_create :set_department

   private

   def set_department
      self.departments.build department: "Test"
   end
end

#app/models/department.rb
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :positions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions

    before_create :set_positions

    private

    def set_positions
       self.positions.build x: y
    end
end
```

... or ...

```
#app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :departments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments, :projects

   before_create :set_departments

   private

   def set_departments
      dpt = self.departments.build department: "Test"
      dpt.positions << Position.new position: "Admin"
      dpt.positions << Position.new position: "Tester"
   end
end
```

--

You can also declare multiple nested attributes on a single line:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :departments, :positions
```

Comment: I am getting the error `syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting keyword_end dept.positions << Position.new position: "Test Art" ^`. My model is `dept.positions << Position.new position: "Test Pos"`

Comment: You may have to wrap in brackets: `dept.positions << Position.new(position: "Test Art")`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new position with:

```
Project.first.positions << Position.create(:foo => 'foo', :bar => 'bar')
```

or

```
position = Position.create(:foo => 'foo', :bar => 'bar')
Department.first.positions << position
Project.first.positions << position
```

Obviously the ".first" is just for illustration and you can use the `<<` notation with any Department or Project instance.

Looking at this again, it seems like a really good fit for polymorphic associations.

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :positioned, polymorphic: true
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions, as: :positioned
end 

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions, as: :positioned
end
```

And in your migration:

```
  create_table :positions do |t|
    ...
    t.integer :positioned_id
    t.string  :positioned_type
    ...
  end
```

There may be a more suitable way to name things for your app but this is the general idea.

Comment: I'm sorry I am having trouble seeing how this works.  I am getting an error saying `<<` is an undefined method.

Comment: << only works for collections (IE `@project.departments << @position`)

Comment: ah, my bad.. left out `.positions` - fixed

Comment: this method doesn't seem to be associating with the department.  I have a column in my positions model for `department_id`, `project_id` and, `position_title`.  Also .first is referencing the first row in the model, which in my case I am trying to create different things for each project.  My .first record is the first one ever created, where I need the first one in the current project being made.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you might do something like this in your Department model:

```
after_create { self.positions.create! }
```

Though this might be a problematic approach. Creating records like this using ActiveRecord callbacks (which is what gives us after_create) can make your whole app really fragile. For example, if you do this, you'll never be able to make a department without an associated position. Perhaps one day you'll need to do just that.

So even though it's not the exact answer to your question, I suggest looking at created these associated models in a service object, or at least in controller code.

Comment: I do allow users to create a department and position individually, I just want a few departments and respective positions to come pre packaged when a user creates a project.

Comment: Then, what I would do, is first just write the code in the relevant controller method, in your case probably users_controller#create. Then I'd probably extract it to a service object or something. But I would not do this in the model.

Comment: In your controller, you can just to something like `department = projects.departments.create; department.positions.create. You would do this in the create action of your controller.